# moment js, converting EST string to UTC

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm a new developer and I have been stuck on this for a while,  how would I convert the following date to it's UTC version (no utc prefix/suffix needed) in moment JS?

```
05/03/2016 16:00
```

I tried:

```
var b = "05/03/2016 16:00";
moment.utc(b).format();
"2016-05-03T16:00:00Z"
```

I would like the final result to be exactly as b, but its UTC equivalent. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the *input format* and the *output format*.

- Without an input format, your date could be interpreted as either May 3rd, or March 5th, depending on the culture.
- Without an output format, moment has no way to know what kind of string you want, so it defaults to the full ISO8601 extended format.

You're also missing the conversion.  If the input is local time and you want UTC, then you should parse it with `moment(...)` then convert it to UTC with the `.utc()` function.

In summary:

```
moment(b, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm').utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')
```

Also note that it's converting from the local time where the code is running.  in your question you asked about EST.  If your local time zone is something else, then EST will not apply to the above.  You would instead need to use the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on to do the following:

```
moment(b, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm', 'America/New_York').utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')
```

Comment: @devdropper87 this answer is better, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
moment(b).utc();
```

Will change it to a utc time, you might still need to add parameters to format() to make sure it displays the way you originally wrote it.

```
moment(b).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm");
```